# Simplify the equation and draw it on number line.

Tags: inequality, number-line

The equation is $x^4-5x^3-4x^2+20x \le 0$. I was able to make factors as follow $x(x+2)(x-2)(x-5)$ now I am stuck and don't know how to find the domain to draw the number line.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! Here, homework-type questions are poorly received. Before asking a [question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), make sure you thoroughly research the topic. For example, before you asked your question, you should've found a page like [this](https://www.wtamu.edu/academic/anns/mps/math/mathlab/col_algebra/col_alg_tut35_polyfun.htm), which is related.

Comment: **Hint**: You have found that the product of $4$ factors is on the left side of your inequality. Can you analyze when such product is less or equal than $0$?